# How to prepare confusion matrix from the predicted class probabilities?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, naivebayes, confusion-matrix

There is a Naive Bayesian classifier which is created with a given training data. In the table, the predicted positive class probabilities and the actual class labels are shown. I want to prepare the confusion matrix but I could not find out how to do it with just knowing the probabilities.

| ID | Actual class label | Predicted positive class probability |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | + | 0.6 |
| 2 | + | 0.8 |
| 3 | - | 0.2 |
| 4 | + | 0.3 |
| 5 | - | 0.4 |

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to have discrete class labels to compute confusion matrix. Define a threshold on the predicted positive class probability to predict class labels (y_pred).
You can then use actual class labels (y_actual) and y_pred to compute the confusion matrix.

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
confusion_matrix(y_actual, y_pred)
```